# How to display multiple list links in one-line for toggle nav in Bootstrap4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

#### Current:

1) click on the 'More' button

2) the navbar extends to bottom, (the brand-logo also extends as well)

2-1) three links appear (FAQ/MAP/FAX) **displaying 3 different links, each taking full width space**

#### Desired Format:

1) click on 'more button'

2) navbar extends to bottom **the brand-logo DOES NOT extend**

2-1) three links appear (FAQ/MAP/FAX) 
each link displays in **One Line**

Codeply: 
http://codeply.com/go/ShOVPZbUaT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the brand-logo from extending (or more correctly align it to the top and override the vertically centered alignment set by default), you could add the `align-items-start` class to your `navbar` like so:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark align-items-start">
```

And to have the `.collapse` tag links on the same vertical line, you could surround the three links with a flex `div` tag. like this:

```
<div class="collapse" id="more">
    <div class="d-flex">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white">FAQ</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white">MAP</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white">FAX</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Both `d-flex` and `align-items-start` are Bootstrap classes.

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/OmarEinea/pen/goWQxV) with those edits.

Hope that helps.

Comment: currently, when i click on the 'more' button, the lists are 'aligned to right'. how do i make this align with the above nav-link features?

Comment: I didn't get your question

Comment: Currently, when you click the **menu button** in **mobile browser**, you see all the **menu links** aligned to the left (right below the brand-logo) area. Ideally, I want the links on the right  (right below the **menu toggler** icon) Thanks!

Comment: you could achieve that by adding `text-right` class to your `a.nav-link` tags, I updated the codepen with this change